# Is there a way to use Items.find() in VBA to extract certain text from Outlook?

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

I need to extract specific text from outlook in bulk (through 9000 emails)

I was wondering would something like this work

```
Dim Folder as Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim sFolders As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim iRow As Integer, oRow As Integer
Dim MailBoxName As String, Pst_Folder_Name  As String, Destination As String

ThisWorkbook.sheets(1).Cells(1,1) = "Destinations"

For iRow = 1 To Folder.Items.Count

ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(oRow, 1) = Folder.Items.Find(Destination)
```

I have only some experience in VBA from years ago and I need am trying to create  system like this for my job so I can pull out the information needed from the Body of an Email instead of scanning through thousands of emails seprately.

Does anyone know some good source/tutorials I can look at? as every one keeps leading me back to the same place

Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying (**Tested from within Outlook**)? Please amend it to run from MS-Excel.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim myFilter As String, SearchString As String
    Dim OutlookTable As Table
    Dim OutlookRow As Row

    '~~> This is your search string. Change as applicable
    SearchString = "Siddharth"

    '~~> Create Query
    myFilter = "@SQL=" & _
               Chr(34) & _
               "urn:schemas:httpmail:textdescription" & _
               Chr(34) & _
               " ci_phrasematch '" & _
               SearchString & _
               "'"

    Set OutlookTable = Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder.GetTable(myFilter)

    Do Until OutlookTable.EndOfTable
        Set OutlookRow = OutlookTable.GetNextRow

        '~~> Print Subject (For example) of that email
        '~~> which has the search string
        Debug.Print OutlookRow("Subject")
    Loop
End Sub
```

> Does anyone know some good source/tutorials I can look at?

**Tutorial**: See this [MSKB Article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff861580.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The Outlook object model provides the [Find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff869662.aspx)/[FindNext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff862482.aspx), [Restrict](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff869597.aspx), `GetTable` and [AdvancedSearch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb219884.aspx) methods for filtering items in Outlook. I'd suggest using the `Restrict` emthod in your case. The `Find` or `FindNext` methods are faster than filtering if there are a small number of items. The `Restrict` method is significantly faster if there is a large number of items in the collection, especially if only a few items in a large collection are expected to be found.

You can read about them and find the sample code in the following articles:

- [How To: Use Find and FindNext methods to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder (C#, VB.NET)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/20/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-mail/)
- [How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/)
- [Advanced search in Outlook programmatically: C#, VB.NET](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2012/05/31/outlook-search-csharp-vbnet/)

[The Filtering Items section in MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff863965.aspx) describes all possible methods in depth.

> Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder.GetTable(myFilter)

Don't ever use multiple dots in the single line of code. It may bring another issue into your code. I always recommend breaking the chain property and methods calls and declaring them on separate lines of code. Thus, you will be able to see under the debugger what each property and method returns and find the cause of the issue easily (if any).